# How to return a state value and use it in a method's if check in Obective C

Tags: objective-c

I need to get the state of the youtubeVideoPlayer and then set to this method in objective-c.

How can I set this state in any other values

```
 - (void)playerView:(YTPlayerView *)playerView didChangeToState:(YTPlayerState)state {
        if (state == kYTPlayerStatePaused || state == kYTPlayerStateEnded) {
            [self setVideoHidden:YES];
        }
        else if (state == kYTPlayerStatePlaying) {
            isPlaying = YES;
            [self setVideoHidden:NO];
        }
    }


-(void) playPreloadedVideoCore:(NSNotification*) notification {
   if (state != kYTPlayerStatePlaying) { // how can i make this state of the player
            ++loadingCount;
            if (loadingCount < 50) {
}
}
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more details, it's not clear what you ask. You receive `state` in `playerView:didChangeToState:` and then you want to use it in another method. You can save `state` as a class ivar or property. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: The problem is I can't able to view the video in my app. I need to set the playerstate and then need to check the  isPlaying = [videosWebView playerState] == kYTPlayerStatePlaying;